# $\int |fg| d\mu \leq ||f||_1||g||_{\infty}.$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

### Let $||f||_{\infty} =\inf\{M:\mu( \{ x: |f(x)|> M \})=0 \}$. Prove that

### $$\int |fg| d\mu \leq ||f||_1||g||_{\infty}.$$

**The way I proceed:**

First I showed that $||f||_{\infty} = \lim_{p\to\infty} ||f||_p$. Then I showed that for any $\epsilon >0$, $\lim_{p\to\infty} \big{|}(||f||_p||f||_q)-(||f||_1||g||_{\infty})\big{|}\leq \epsilon$$(*)$. Using Holder's inequality and $(*)$ I claimed that  $\int |fg| d\mu \leq ||f||_1||g||_{\infty}.$

The problem is that where I found this problem(Durrett) they have the exercise $||f||_{\infty} = \lim_{p\to\infty} ||f||_p$ after the given problem. So there must be a way to solve this problem without using $||f||_{\infty} = \lim_{p\to\infty} ||f||_p$, can anyone tell how is that?

Comment: Why not just use the fact that $|g|\leq ||g||_{\infty}$ a.e., so $|fg|\leq |f|\cdot||g||_{\infty}$ a.e.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

One is via Hölder, where you notice that $\displaystyle \int |fg| = ||fg||_1$, then see that $||fg||_1\leq ||f||_1 ||g||_\infty$. The proof I did of Hölder allows $p=1$, $q=\infty$.

For the other, you use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that $|fg|$ is integrable, as it is bounded almost everywhere by $M|f|$, where $M = ||g||_\infty$. Then, $$\int |fg| \leq \int M|f| \\ \int |fg| \leq M\int |f| \\ \int |fg| \leq ||g||_\infty \int |f| \\ ||fg||_1\leq ||f||_1 ||g||_\infty$$

Comment: The second way doesn't use the dominated convergence theorem (there are no sequences of functions converging). Rather it uses that $f \le g$ a.e. $\implies \int f d\mu \le int g d\mu$.

Comment: $f,g$ are measurable, so $fg$ is measurable, so $|fg|$ is nonnegative and measurable, so there is a sequence of simple functions that converges (monotonically) to it, by DCT $|fg|$ is integrable.

Comment: you're right, i did skip some detail in proving $|fg|$ integrable

Comment: Once you've proven it is integrable, there is no reason to refer back to the sequence of simple functions. Just because there is a sequence of simple functions converging a.e. to $\lvert fg \rvert$ does not mean $\lvert f g \rvert$ is integrable. That is a separate property which is proved by noting that $\lvert f g \rvert \le \| g \|_\infty \lvert f \rvert$ a.e. and $f$ is integrable. There is no use of DCT here.

Comment: the method I used in the above comment can be generalized to prove the property you mentioned, I was applying it to the specific case